# Waterproofing leaking canvas on a pop-up camper

Tags: camping, waterproofing, car-camping, canvas

We have a pop-up camper that has seen better days.  Last summer the canvas covering the bed ends began to leak in a few critical places, and we are looking for a solution that stops short of buying all new canvas.  I am thinking about purchasing a spray-on waterproofing product like Aqua Armor but don't have any experience with this kind of product and would appreciate suggestions.  In particular, I would like to know:

> - Does anybody have experience waterproofing the canvas on a pop-up camper?
> - Aqua Armor advertises a product with the phrase "for Tent & Gear" in its name, and another with the phrase "for Natural Fabrics" in its name.  Which would make more sense to use for this purpose?  The "Natural Fabrics" one is advertised as being non-solvent based, which is appealing (we are going to be sleeping underneath that fabric and would prefer not to breathe in solvent fumes) but I also want something that will be very effective at keeping out the rain.

If anybody can recommend something better to do, I would also appreciate that.

Answer (score 7):

If its true canvas (cotton) and its leaking its pretty much past its best before date and replacement is the most reliable solution. Good news is Canvas takes water proofing products well and as long as its not rotten, should last you a many more seasons with the occasional re coat.

Its been a long time since I have had to do a tent or similar. Its best to get a good, heavy duty product designed for canvas tents rather than synthetic products. In my experience (many years ago now) Aerosol cans worked for raincoats and touching up seams, but were designed to leave no trace and only left a light coating that quickly wears off.

You are probably better to get a heavy duty liquid product than can be brushed or sprayed on and will last longer. For a long lasting waterproofing, you need to soak canvas - which may mean working it in with a brush, not put a light layer over the top. Unlike a rain coat, stiffening fabric and such is not an issue for a tent, so a more robust formulation can be used. You are definitely better to get a tent specific waterproofing product   rather than one that does "Raincoats, fabrics and tents"

If the fabric is not canvas, but a synthetic PVC type product, you are less likely to be successful at water proofing it. Its still worth a try - get a product specifically for synthetics.